# keil uVision arm

Tags: assembly, keil, arm7

i try to translate this code in uVision(Device: Arm7), 
but i get 9 Error´s, what is wrong?
I thing my configs are wrong.
Thanks

```
/* Daten-Bereich */
AREA   Daten, DATA, READWRITE
Wert: DW  10
 Quadrat:DS 4

 /********************************************************************/
    /* Programm-Bereich */
  AREA   Programm, CODE, READONLY, AT 0x00000000
  Reset_Handler:  MSR     CPSR_c, #0x10 ; User Mode aktivieren
  /********************************************************************/
                LDR     R3,=Wert        ; Adresse des Werts laden
            LDRH    R1,[R3]         ; Wert laden
            MUL     R2,R1,R1        ; Quadrat bilden
            LDR     R3,=Quadrat     ; Adresse des Quadrats 
            STR     R2,[R3]         ; Quadrat ablegen

                endlos:         B       endlos


            END


Assembler_Startup.s(4): error: A1163E: Unknown opcode Quadrat: , expecting opcode or Macro
 Assembler_Startup.s(6): error: A1137E: Unexpected characters at end of line
 Assembler_Startup.s(7): error: A1137E: Unexpected characters at end of line
 Assembler_Startup.s(8): error: A1207E: Bad or unknown attribute
 Assembler_Startup.s(9): error: A1163E: Unknown opcode Reset_Handler: , expecting opcode or Macro
 Assembler_Startup.s(10): error: A1137E: Unexpected characters at end of line
 Assembler_Startup.s(19): error: A1163E: Unknown opcode endlos: , expecting opcode or Macro
 Assembler_Startup.s - 9 Error(s), 0 Warning(s).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to make changes in your Startup file??
Using embedded C language would be much more easy in writing this code...

Think on it!!